# Schengen visa validity of 8 days

Tags: visas, schengen

My problem is that I have a Schengen C single visa issued by  theLithuanian embassy in Russia for just 8 days stay (23/03/16-30/03/16) and I don't understand it… I don't know if it's possible to visit another Schengen country with this minimum number of days before it elapses.

I am a student in Russia just wand to spend the Easter holidays outside.

Comment: It indicatesLithuanian: Šengeno valstybėse on top

Comment: Yeah. I will enter Lithuania 23rd. I wanted to go to Italy on the 24th and come to Lithuania 26th. Wanted to if possible with a return flight ticket I will not be restricted by checks

Comment: Your proposed trip to Italy should be fine as long as the flight either is direct or has stops only in Schengen airports.

Answer (score 4):

Your visa should indicate which countries it's valid for.  Most commonly, the indication will be *Schengen states,* or, rather, the equivalent in the language of the issuing country (Lithuanian: *Šengeno valstybėse*).  If your visa is like this, then you may visit other Schengen countries during the visa's period of validity.

The heading for this item appears to be *GALIOJA.*

Because the visa is a single-entry visa, you must be careful not to leave the Schengen area before you are ready to leave for good.  For example, if you want to go to Poland, you may not travel by land through the Kaliningrad Oblast, nor via Belarus.  You would either have to cross the Lithuania-Poland border directly, or travel by a direct air or sea connection.

Comment: Lithuanian: Šengeno valstybėse

Comment: @ishmaelGyasi in that case, you may add any Schengen country to your itinerary.  Be aware, however, that if you show up in Portugal with no evidence of any intention of going to Lithuania, you might be denied entry because it looks like you're not using the visa for the purpose you claimed in your application.  A short side trip to any Schengen country is fine, however.

Comment: @phoog if I remember correctly, the first point of entry should be to the country which issued the visa

Comment: @littleadv not at all. Someone holding a Schengen visa, including a limited-duration single-entry visa, can transit through any Schengen country or countries to reach the issuing country (unless there is a specially noted restriction invalidating the visa for any country or countries, of course).

Comment: @littleadv, a typical example would be flying to a German airport and then taking a train to Poland. That would be entering the Schengen area in Germany with a Schengen visa issued by Poland.

Comment: @littleadv it more recently occurred to me that we don't even need to discuss transit to disprove the "first country should be the country issuing the visa" rule.  For example, someone planning a vacation with one week in country A followed by three weeks in country B is generally *required* to get the visa from country B, even if the itinerary calls for entry through country B.